# I am having difficulty rendering a complete png from an animation

Tags: rendering

I am trying to render an animation as PNG but it is not rendering a complete image.

[Blend file](http://%20https://pasteall.org/media/f/8/f843cbc033ceee27c951f9fd32a111ff.blend)

Comment: hello, please don't write in capitals

Comment: Okay i will remember that for next time @chris

Comment: You can still edit your text   ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a video sequence in your *Video Editor*, and the *Sequencer* option is enabled in the *Output > Post Processing* panel, so either remove the video or disable the option:

[image]

Comment: Okay , thank you so so much @moonboots

Comment: @tanyagarg, as much as I hate to see moonboots' reputation growing, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1059900) their answer.

Comment: @ Marty Fouts, ah ah ^^